# Gitlab: Show unmerged commits over N git repos

Tags: git, gitlab

I have about 10 git repos which have a branch called `feature-foo` in gitlab.

Background: There is one core-project and nine repos for optional plugins.

I think all branches should be merged since months, and I would like to delete these branches.

Is there a way to show all unmerged commits of all repos which have this branch?

For the shell I hacked this, which shows all revisions which are not merged:

```
parallel  "[ -d {} ] ||exit; echo; echo {}; cd {} || exit; git rev-parse -q --verify remotes/origin/feature-foo || exit; git rev-list remotes/origin/feature-foo --not master --no-merges " ::: *
```

Above script just prints out the revisions, I could extend the script but I would prefer a nice GUI via Gitlab.

Hint: I am not fixed on my current strategy. I am happy with anything which gets me to the goal: See unmerged commits of branch name `feature-foo` looping over N repos.

Comment: Google's 'Repo' is what you need. It's originally used to manage Android code, which has over 400 repos.

Comment: @ElpieKay you mean this: https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/ ? Looks cool, never heard of it before. Thank you.